# Is there a way to create a namespace with generalized attributes?

Tags: c++, c++14

I know the following piece of source code is not valid C++ code, but just to illustrate my question:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace mylib {
    using deprecated = [[deprecated]];
}

[[mylib::deprecated]] void deprecated_function() {
    std::cout << "Calling deprecated function!" << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
    deprecated_function();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve such a thing? The intention is to drop the `#define`s and use attribute specifiers exclusively -- excluding the compiler guards and verifications, because that will most certainly demand some degree of preprocessing-fu proficiency :) (but then, [predef is your friend](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/)).

For example:

```
// mylib-config.hpp
namespace mylib {
    #if __cplusplus > 201402L // C++17 has support for [[deprecated]]
        using deprecated = [[deprecated]]

    #elif defined(__clang)
        using deprecated = [[clang::deprecated]]

    #elif defined(__GNUC__)
        using deprecated = [[gnu::deprecated]]

    #else // What to do? Is there a placeholder?
        // Starting C++17, this invalid attribute should be ignored.
        // Before that, the result is implementation-defined.
        // (Is there any chance for undefined behaviour in this case?)
        using deprecated = [[completely_invalid_identifier__]];
    #endif
}

// mylib.hpp
[[mylib::deprecated]] void deprecated_function();
```

My current solution is to use `#define`s where an attribute would be, e.g.:

```
// mylib-config.hpp
#if __cplusplus > 201402L
    #define mylib_DEPRECATED [[deprecated]]

#elif defined(__clang)
    #define mylib_DEPRECATED [[clang::deprecated]]

#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    #define mylib_DEPRECATED [[gnu::deprecated]]

#else
    #define mylib_DEPRECATED
#endif

// mylib.hpp
mylib_DEPRECATED void deprecated_function();
```

If normalizing all the attributes used by your application in a namespace of your own is indeed possible, how would you account for the absence of a specific attribute on some compilers? (e.g. attributes that would apply only to GCC but would not be required on other toolchains).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't put attributes in namespaces, or associate them with namespaces. Just define a macro. Put the definition in a header such that different compilers will pick up different, suitable versions of that header.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I'm applying right now, I just wondered if I was overlooking anything in the standard that would allow me to contextualize attributes. If that's the way it is, I think attribute specifiers provide no real improvements to current compiler-dependent attributes as of now (or at least until most compilers have decent C++17 support, where unknown attributes are just ignored). BTW, do you think there's any possibility for the committee to add "user-namespaced" attribute specifiers?

Comment: @FlávioLisbôa: I don't know, but have a look at (https://isocpp.org/forums). Maybe ask in one of the groups listed there.